# Will my stove's pilot light ignite automatically when the gas is turned back on?

Tags: gas, stove, pilot-light

I shut off the gas valve going to my stove because the top was getting too hot when off. I know its supposed to be warm because of the pilot lights but this was hot. I suspect the pilot light is cranked up too high. I'm going to have my landlord look at it. My question is, if I turn the gas back on, do the pilot lights automatically re-light?

Comment: Does a car have four cylinders? (Please revise to include some specific information about the stove in question. We can't help otherwise.)

Comment: Nope. Call the gas company to relight pilots.

Comment: @isherwood I'm at work right now but I'll check when I get back home. Honestly, its so old, I think all the branding is worn off haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there were a way to spark the pilot light automatically, you would not even have the pilot light at all (you would just use THAT thing to spark the flame only when needed).   This is how my stove works:  I have no pilot light, but I have "spark plugs" at the burners (they make a loud clicking noise when the gas knob is in the Start position).

So, by definition, if you have pilot lights, then you need them.  If you snuffed them then you need to be ready to re-kindle them, they won't re-kindle themselves.

Comment: Agreed standing pilots are easy to relight , I have has stove tops that had a little air hole next to the pilot placing a match in the hole would light it. On some models we have had to raise the lid and light it. The spot above the pilot will get hot to test out how hot put a match under a skillet, the skillet may be thicker metal and it can get hot enough to blister if you did a couple of matches in the same place 1 after another a match is not much different than a pilot.+

Answer (score 0):

If has a pilot flame usually no, but automatic valve will stay closed so no risk of gas leakage nor explosion, if your is pilot-less yes, because flame is turned on 'on request' by an electric spark. The important thing is that the boiler is not locked by 'autosensing' absence of gas. My boiler tries to self start 3 times for about 5 seconds, if gas isn't coming (so flame doesn't ignite), it'll go into 'block' and I have to manually reset it to get it work again.

Comment: Not a boiler. Most stoves with standing pilots do NOT have a valve that prevents gas flow when the pilot is not lit, unlike most water heaters or boilers that DO have such a valve. Most standing pilot stoves are also old (and have one that's much more annoying to reach under the oven, as well as the easy to get to stovetop pilots.)

Comment: Here, (Italy) it's almost 40 years you can't find new ranges without automatic gas shut-off, in boilers even before... If OP is using a 50years old stove... he may just consider replacement, just for safety reasons.

Comment: In the USA, my impression (as a user, not an industry insider) is that stoves went from standing pilot (and no thermocouple gas valve) to electronic (spark) ignition without passing through an automatic valve phase. And I know plenty of 50 year old gas stoves that still work fine.